# LXC Container | I want to implement database Indexing Mechanism as a feature in container

Tags: mysql, linux, lxc, linux-containers

I am new to Linux Containers ,but I want to implement Indexing Mechanism for Databases system into LXC Container as a feature such that Indexing System is shared across all hosts of LXC Container?
Any high level Ideas of how to implement it? How to apply patch of existing database indexing system like MYSQL to LXC container's source code ?